# Strange problems with MySQL datetime query

Tags: mysql

How do these results make sense? I don't understand.
Shouldn't for example the last query return an empty set since that there are no threads with date `> 2010`? Why does it return a result from 2003?

```
mysql> SELECT * 
       FROM thread 
       WHERE newsgroup_id = '64654' 
       AND 'thread_date' < '2010-09-10 21:43:05' 
       LIMIT 1;
```

Empty set (0.00 sec)

```
mysql> SELECT * 
       FROM thread 
       WHERE newsgroup_id = '64654' 
       AND 'thread_date' < '2000-09-10 21:43:05' 
       LIMIT 1;
```

Empty set (0.00 sec)

```
mysql> SELECT * 
       FROM thread 
       WHERE newsgroup_id = '64654' 
       AND 'thread_date' > '2000-09-10 21:43:05' 
       LIMIT 1;
+--------------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
| newsgroup_id | thread_id | postcount | hash     | thread_date         | thread_date_last        | thread_title                    | title_has_valid_charset |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
|        64654 |         1 |         0 | O2gvcPRl | 2003-06-06 22:51:24 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | Vendo fotodigit  2.1  megapixel |                       0 |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

```
mysql> SELECT * 
       FROM thread 
       WHERE newsgroup_id = '64654' 
       AND 'thread_date' > '2010-09-10 21:43:05' 
       LIMIT 1;
+--------------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
| newsgroup_id | thread_id | postcount | hash     | thread_date         | thread_date_last    | thread_title                    | title_has_valid_charset |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
|        64654 |         1 |         0 | O2gvcPRl | 2003-06-06 22:51:24 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | Vendo fotodigit  2.1  megapixel |                       0 |
+--------------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: If I'm correct, you can't do this. This is just an ASCII comparison (text based) and that's why you are getting these weird but 'correct' comparisons. Look up how to compare date/time in mysql

Comment: @Nupul: you do can compare datetime as if they were strings in MySQL

Comment: @ypercube: My bad...should have clarified. I meant the overall comparison is string based (both LHS and RHS of `<,>`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using wrong type of quotes. MySQL thinks that you are comparing string "thread_date". Here is how it should be:

```
`thread_date` > '2010-09-10 21:43:05'
```

This way MySQL knows that you mean field `thread_date` and compares it to the date at the right side of expression.

Comment: Or no backquotes at all: `... AND thread_date > '2010-09-10 21:43:05' ...`

Answer (score 0):

`'thread_date'` is a string, not the value of that field.

You meant:

```
`thread_date` > '2010-09-10 21:43:05'
```